# Encrypt a String in Python That Just Can Decrypt with str encrypted with

Tags: python, encryption

I Want To Encrypt User Passwords With Their Password

I Mean That The Encrypted String

Can Only Decrypt With The Main Password User Entered

> User Entered 12345 for Password 
>  The Encrypted Value Only Can Decrypt With 12345 Key

Comment: Please, add more context to your question

Comment: Well, usually you *hash* passwords, and you never unhash them.. you just hash the passwords users send to you and compare that hash to what you have stored, this way you aren't farming a bunch of plaintext passwords from your users. There's no real reason for you to encrypt/decrypt a password for a user unless your goal is to phish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Was Exactly The Main Topic I Deal With Last Week
I Wanna Describe The Way I Do This

> Generate Key From User Input with **Crypto.Cipher & AES**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
cipher = AES.new(convert(input), AES.MODE_ECB)
```

> When The KEY generated you can encrypt your string with cipher

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(input.rjust(32)))
```

Thats All : - )

Comment: Thats Way I Need; Thanks sina